# Should I put irrelevant jobs on my resume?

Tags: resume, job-search

I'm a fresh college grad trying to get into the IT industry. I graduated with an Information Systems degree two months ago. I worked as a sales rep, valet, software and hardware mobile technician. I do know Java, python, C#, SQL, and other languages but I only have in class experience.

I couldn't afford to do internship, since most of the ones I could find were unpaid. I was basically paying my way through school, and couldn't afford to live without an income (though I did graduate with $0 debt!)

I am looking into an analyst role and don't know whether to include my irrelevant jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two sets of skills that are needed:

- Job specific skills, such as programming languages
- General job-keeping skills, such as being where you are supposed to be, on time, appropriately dressed and equipped for what you are doing.

Some of your jobs may not say much about your programming skills, but can still demonstrate reliability and willingness to work. Until you have enough jobs in your field to show that, you should keep the "irrelevant" jobs on your resume.

Comment: How likely are companies willing to give an internship to grads? I honestly wouldn't mind doing an internship to get some experience first but if it's too late, I'll jump right in and start looking for full-time positions.

Comment: @Killer066 That is a new question. You should check for duplicates, and post it as a question if it has not already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 2):

Jobs are almost never entirely irrelevant - especially when you've just graduated.

Put relevant skills on your resume.

Find instances of teamwork, problem solving, working independently to achieve a goal, that kind of thing. Try and get a reference letter written up pointing out punctuality and hard work.

Comment: Do you think most employers care whether an applicant has any student loans? I was thinking putting that in there but wasn't sure

Comment: Not on a resume. Might mention it in your cover letter - focus on the work aspect, so they now you're a hard worker.

Comment: @Killer066 Your résumé (or CV; for these purposes, they are one and the same) is a sales pitch, or brochure if you prefer. Its purpose is to get your foot in the door so you can have an interview where you can show the company what a great hire you would be (and find out whether or not *you* want to work for that company.) *Don't put anything in your résumé that doesn't "sell" you and your skills* to the company you are applying to, but also don't put anything in it that isn't the truth. Lying or even just "sugar-coating" things can come back and haunt you. Do present everything carefully.

Answer (score 1):

At this point in your career there are no jobs that are irrelevant, but it helps to put in how the skills you learned there will benefit your new employers.

Don't:
Job - Valet
Duties - Parked cars

Do:
Job - Valet
Duties - Responsible for safely and effectively moving customers vehicles, with a focus on making sure they were organized in a manner that would allow for fastest retrieval.

When in doubt focus on the customer service aspects of whatever job you were doing.  Regardless of the role, being able to communicate effectively with another party is always useful.

Comment: My problem is relating my Valet job to my degree (Information Systems). That's the hard part for me.

Comment: @Killer066 you just have to spin it to highlight your organized and logical thinking.  What sort of IF/THEN statements did you go through in your head when deciding where to park a car?

Comment: The valet company uses a software that tells them flight info, customer arrival times, services they requested etc..This is what I put in bullets on my resume:

Comment: **• Lowered customer wait times at airports by providing up-to-date customer flight information data to employees to ensure customer satisfaction.**
**•Reduced customer acquisition costs by negotiating pricing and fees with customers’ employers while ensuring the continuation and enhancement of services**

Comment: @Killer066 sounds like a useful job to me!

Comment: Thanks. It's a weird company though. They have no marketing department, one HR person, one IT person, one accountant (who was fired for cooking the books lol), and that's it! I would HATE to be the only IT person in a company!